# SQL Server stored procedure stops when outputting temp table inside transaction

Tags: sql-server, transactions, trace

In a SQL Server 2008 (sp2) stored procedure, before starting a transaction I create two temporary tables. I insert into them in the transaction. When the transaction loops through a fairly large set of data (~1,200 times), the stored procedure fails to finish. Specifically, a trace shows that

```
SELECT * FROM #tmpTable2
```

in the below code starts but doesn't complete. When the loop is about half as big, it works fine.

```
IF [true] > 0 --error
BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM #tmpTable1
    SELECT * FROM #tmpTable2
    DROP TABLE #tmpTable1
    DROP TABLE #tmpTable2
    rollback TRANSACTION
    return -1
END
```

Note that in the trace, `transactionlog` events occur more and more frequently as it gets to the point it fails.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Is it possible you're running out of transaction log space?

Comment: why are you doing inserts in a loop? That is usually the worse possible way to do them.

Comment: I'll look into increasing log space.It's looping through input data.

Comment: Also, I noticed that the CREATE TABLE lines happen before the transaction starts. Isn't it bad practice to put DROP TABLE inside the transaction? What will happen? Could it be the reason for the failure? (This is not my code!)

Comment: The drop tables will be rolled back, meaning that they will exist until the session ends